# R append new rows based on original rows

Tags: r, append, row, data-manipulation

I am new in R and I want to add lots of new rows based on original one.
First, I show my part of data:

```
Type    Time            PM
Ac      2016-01         7710
Ac      2016-02         27500
Ac      2016-03         12840
Ac      2016-04         20060
Ac      2016-05         9430
Ac      2016-06         9830
Ac      2016-07         3870
Ac      2016-08         12040
Ac      2016-09         5590
Ac      2016-10         4300
Ac      2016-11         3870
Ac      2016-12         2580
As      2016-01         315052
As      2016-02         478542
As      2016-03         491472
As      2016-04         662238
As      2016-05         464728
As      2016-06         530424
As      2016-07         443122
As      2016-08         603512
As      2016-09         564438
As      2016-10         440068
As      2016-11         462846
As      2016-12         525394
HW      2015-12           7250
```

Second, what I want is like following(I subset `Type Ac`, `Time 2016-01 & 2016-03 & 2016-10` as example):

```
Type    Time    Time2   LapseMonth  PM      What I want
Ac  2016-01     2016-01     0       7710    315.9836066
Ac  2016-01     2016-02     1       0       610.9016393
Ac  2016-01     2016-03     2       0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-01     2016-04     3       0       631.9672131
Ac  2016-01     2016-05     4       0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-01     2016-06     5       0       631.9672131
Ac  2016-01     2016-07     6       0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-01     2016-08     7       0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-01     2016-09     8       0       631.9672131
Ac  2016-01     2016-10     9       0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-01     2016-11     10      0       631.9672131
Ac  2016-01     2016-12     11      0       653.0327869
Ac  2016-03     2016-03     0       12840   526.2295082
Ac  2016-03     2016-04     1       0       1052.459016
Ac  2016-03     2016-05     2       0       1087.540984
Ac  2016-03     2016-06     3       0       1052.459016
Ac  2016-03     2016-07     4       0       1087.541
Ac  2016-03     2016-08     5       0       1087.541
Ac  2016-03     2016-09     6       0       1052.459
Ac  2016-03     2016-10     7       0       1087.541
Ac  2016-03     2016-11     8       0       1052.459
Ac  2016-03     2016-12     9       0       1087.541
Ac  2016-10     2016-10     0       4300    176.2295082
Ac  2016-10     2016-11     1       0       352.4590164
Ac  2016-10     2016-12     2       0       364.2076503
```

I explain the result I want:
1. `Time2` is a new column which is the month equal and after `Time`.
2. `LapseMonth` is also a new column which is equal to month(`Time2`) - month(`Time`). Thus, it generates as above.
3. Column `What I want` is complicated.
   Look at row1(`Time`:2016-01, `Time2`:2016-01, `LapseMonth`:0, `PM`:7710, `What I want`:315.9836066)
   When `Time` = `Time1`, the formula of `What I want` is **15/366*PM**, which PM=7710
   And the following is the **day of that month**/366*PM (i.e. row2:610.9016393 = 29/366*7710, riow3:653.0327869 = 31/366*7710)

I add each row by row, but it is inefficient when there are many `type`.
I think maybe I can use `for-loop` or `ifelse` to figure out. However, I still have no idea to begin.

I add my code below. Since my data contains multiple excel, so I read it at one time:

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
file.list <- dir(path = "filename", pattern='\\.xlsx', full.names = T)
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
df <- rbindlist(df.list)
df<-as.data.table(df)
df[,Time:=as.Date(Time,"%Y-%m")]
```

The `Time` format changes to Date but the value all missing.  What's going on? **[SOLVED]**

```
df$Time <- ymd( paste( df$Time, 01, sep = "-"))
```

then see @Erdem Akkas's answer and run the code.

There are somethimg very special.
Look at my last obs. of data: `HW      2015-12       7250`
When `Time` is **2015**, the result I need is different with `Time` in **2016**.
What I want is like following:

```
Type    Time    Time2   LapseMonth  PM      What I want
HW   2015-12    2015-12      0      7250    297.1311475
HW   2015-12    2016-01      1      0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-02      2      0       574.4535519
HW   2015-12    2016-03      3      0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-04      4      0       594.2622951
HW   2015-12    2016-05      5      0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-06      6      0       594.2622951
HW   2015-12    2016-07      7      0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-08      8      0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-09      9      0       594.2622951
HW   2015-12    2016-10      10     0       614.0710382
HW   2015-12    2016-11      11     0       594.2622951
HW   2015-12    2016-12      12     0       316.9398907
```

Above is when `Time` in 2015, `What I want` I actually need.
I know it is very complex, so I explain it in the following.
1. When `Time` is **2015**, no matter what month, `LapseMonth` is not the same when `Time` is **2016**. `LapseMonth` must has 0~12 when `Time` in 2015.(see above)
2. Column `What I want` is the same calculation when `Time` in 2016. However, there is one special case. When `LapseMonth` is equal to **12**, the value of `What I want` is original value minus the value of `What I want` when `LapseMonth`=0.  Here is weird.
   *original value* in this example is 614.0710382, because Dec has 31 days. Thus, 614.0710382 = PM*31/366 = 7250*31/366.
   The value of `What I want` when `LapseMonth` is equal to **12** is 614.0710382 - 297.1311475.

Comment: I have similar question like this. Hoping that someone can help.

Comment: Your 'dayofthatmonth' is confusing.  How did you get 15 for the first row ie. 2016/1/1 and in the next one as 29

Comment: @akrun I know it is weird to get 15 for first row, but it is a special case. Take Jan as an example. For  all time=time2, we use 15. Similarly, take Oct as example. When time=time2, the numerator is 15.

Comment: @akrun In addition, second row is 29 because it is Feb, and Feb 2016 has 29 days. Thus, third row the day of that month is 31 because it is Mar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df<-read.table(text="Type    Time            PM
           Ac      2016/1/1    7710
           Ac      2016/2/1    27500
           Ac      2016/3/1    12840
           Ac      2016/4/1    20060
           Ac      2016/5/1    9430
           Ac      2016/6/1    9830
           Ac      2016/7/1    3870
           Ac      2016/8/1    12040
           Ac      2016/9/1    5590
           Ac      2016/10/1   4300
           Ac      2016/11/1   3870
           Ac      2016/12/1   2580
           As      2016/1/1    315052
           As      2016/2/1    478542
           As      2016/3/1    491472
           As      2016/4/1    662238
           As      2016/5/1    464728
           As      2016/6/1    530424
           As      2016/7/1    443122
           As      2016/8/1    603512
           As      2016/9/1    564438
           As      2016/10/1   440068
           As      2016/11/1   462846
           As      2016/12/1   525394",header=T)

dt<-as.data.table(df)
dt[,Time:=as.Date(Time,"%Y/%m/%d")]
dtapp<-dt[rep(1:.N,12-month(Time)+1)]
dtapp[,LapseMonth := seq_len(.N)-1, by =.(Type,Time,PM) ]
dtapp[,Time2:=Time-days(mday(Time)-1)+months(LapseMonth)]
dtapp[,`What I want`:=ifelse(Time==Time2,PM*15/366,PM*days_in_month(Time2)/366)]

dtapp
Type       Time     PM LapseMonth      Time2 What I want
1:   Ac 2016-01-01   7710          0 2016-01-01     315.984
2:   Ac 2016-01-01   7710          1 2016-02-01     610.902
3:   Ac 2016-01-01   7710          2 2016-03-01     653.033
4:   Ac 2016-01-01   7710          3 2016-04-01     631.967
5:   Ac 2016-01-01   7710          4 2016-05-01     653.033
---                                                         
152:   As 2016-10-01 440068          1 2016-11-01   36071.148
153:   As 2016-10-01 440068          2 2016-12-01   37273.519
154:   As 2016-11-01 462846          0 2016-11-01   18969.098
155:   As 2016-11-01 462846          1 2016-12-01   39202.803
156:   As 2016-12-01 525394          0 2016-12-01   21532.541
```

Comment: thanks. I explain the day of that month in the above comment. please check. very appreciate.

Comment: right, but is it efficient? I mean if I have lots of obs., does it take lots of time? thank you. Your answer is awesome.

Comment: No, `data.table` is the most efficient as I know. You can remove some lines through the code like: remove `dtapp[,month_day:=days_in_month(Time2)]
` and change below `dtapp[,`What I want`:=ifelse(Time==Time2,PM*15/366,PM*days_in_month(Time2)/366)]`

Comment: I update my data above and add some code. But `Time` value are all missing (NA).

Comment: oh, I figure out by adding `df$Time <- ymd( paste( df$Time, 01, sep = "-"))` at first then run your answer. It's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: sorry, I want to realize your code. Can you explain this line?  `dtapp[,Time2:=Time-days(mday(Time)-1)+months(monthseq-1)]`

Comment: @Peter Chen mday returns the day of the month as a decimal number (01-31).

Comment: @ErdemAkkas your answer is very good and clear. But I have a question. Except *removing `dtapp[,month_day:=days_in_month(Time2)]`  and changing `dtapp[,What I want:=ifelse(Time==Time2,PM*15/366,PM*days_in_month(Time2)/3‌​66)]`*, can it not use `month_to_generate`?

Comment: @PeterTW `days_in_month` is not equal to `month_to_generate`? `days_in_month` gives number of days in a month, whereas `month_to_generate` gives number of months.

Comment: @PeterChen I have removed some lines in code. Now it is shorter.

Comment: @ErdemAkkas Your update answer explains my question. Thanks! It doesn't need `month_to_generate`, the code can be simplified.

Comment: @ErdemAkkas I have some special case when `Time` is in 2015. I edit my question and add some additional explanation. Can you help me how to figure out? Thanks.

Comment: I edit this line: `dtapp <- dt[ifelse(year(Time)==2016,rep(1:.N,12-month(Time)+1),rep(1:.N,13))]` . However, not true

Comment: I think I cannot use `.N`. But, I have no idea here.

Comment: It seems you have added another question for that.

Comment: @ErdemAkkas oh, so I need to post a new question?